# VHDL shift_right number

Tags: vhdl

I want to divide a number by 512 meaning that I need to shift it by 9. For example in my code I want to take the number 26 in binary form to multiply by 100 and then divide it by 512. But instead of dividing by 512 all I need to do is to shift right 9 times the number 26*100. But when I do the `shift_right` command I get the following error:

> Error (10511): VHDL Qualified Expression error at Multiplier_VHDL .vhd(34): SHIFT_RIGHT type specified in Qualified Expression must match std_logic_vector type that is implied for expression by context

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;

entity Multiplier_VHDL is
    GENERIC (
        display_resolution : INTEGER := 23; -- counter to get to the lowest frequency
        display_counter: INTEGER := 8);     -- counter to get to 97KHz frequency

    port (
        Nibble1 : in std_logic_vector(display_counter downto 0) := "000011010"; -- 26 in binary form
        Nibble2 : in std_logic_vector(display_counter downto 0);
        Result: out std_logic_vector(17 downto 0));
end entity Multiplier_VHDL;

architecture Behavioral of Multiplier_VHDL is
    signal number : unsigned(display_counter downto 0) := "001100100"; -- 100 in binary form

begin
    Result <= std_logic_vector(unsigned(Nibble1) * unsigned(number));
    Result <= (shift_right(unsigned(number), display_counter + 1));

end architecture Behavioral;
```

Comment: your code has many problems and issues. 1. Nibble1 has a generic length, but the default value is always 9 bits, so the display_counter generic must be 8. You have the same problem with the "number" signal. 2. "Result" has multiple drivers 3. Number signal is unassigned. 3. Nibble1 * nibble2 gives a result that is display_counter*2 + 2 bits wide. But you have no signal matching this width.. 4. There is no divide by 512, only divide by 2**(display_counter+1).
Please fix the code example

Comment: ok I fixed the problem ,thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

shift_right returns either unsigned or signed, depending on what you give it.  So you're trying to write an unsigned to a std_logic_vector (Result is of type std_logic_vector).

Also, `number` is already of type `unsigned` so there's no need to cast it to `unsigned` again.

But I give you +1 point for using numeric_std rather than std_logic_arith.